# How can I combine CKEditor and Highlight Textarea?

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I have a textarea which is utilising https://github.com/lonekorean/highlight-within-textarea

This works great; highlighting keywords via regex, however, when applying the CKEditor (http://ckeditor.com/) to it, the highlighting breaks.

How can I use both of of these without conflicts or how can I highlight text with regex within a CKEditor textarea?

Comment: Won't work together. You would need CKEditor plugin to do this

Comment: Do you know of any specific ones?

Comment: Not off hand....should be relatively easy to search for though

Comment: Yea I couldn't find anything. I'll keep looking